transaction execution reverted worldchain
I'm trying to create a code that sends Worldcoin through Worldchain using a master wallet that pays for the gas, but when I try to send it, I get an error. I’m not sure what’s causing it; this is the error:
Saldo de ETH en wei para pagar comisiones: 453514483975334
Saldo de ETH formateado para pagar comisiones: 0.000453514483975334
Saldo actual de Worldcoin: 1,0 WLD
Datos para transferir: {
  from: '0xD6C7481C875fBb69a07eC4e39Df6c690ABC69568',
  to: '0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F',
  value: 1000000000000000000n,
  gas: 500000,
  deadline: 1731459014,
  data: '0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000009ab93ebb695c119efd89a0e44919fb0d6aba2dc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000'
}
Transacción enviada: 0xc32c9a7ddcfd29c84915ca77e8df885a70998d216725d5c48e435506e5d12161
Error: transaction execution reverted (action="sendTransaction", data=null, reason=null, invocation=null, revert=null, transaction={ "data": "", "from": "0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776", "to": "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F" }, receipt={ "_type": "TransactionReceipt", "blobGasPrice": null, "blobGasUsed": null, "blockHash": "0x05fe89a7c818f1d53c955eaeeb2879dc271457a3e6d1ca1373c82b6bb367c775", "blockNumber": 6059890, "contractAddress": null, "cumulativeGasUsed": "112698", "from": "0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776", "gasPrice": "1000264", "gasUsed": "25695", "hash": "0xc32c9a7ddcfd29c84915ca77e8df885a70998d216725d5c48e435506e5d12161", "index": 2, "logs": [  ], "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "root": null, "status": 0, "to": "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.4)
    at makeError (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at assert (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:149:15)
    at checkReceipt (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider.js:1127:35)
    at JsonRpcProvider.txListener (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider.js:1173:33)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'sendTransaction',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F',
    from: '0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776',
    data: ''
  },
  receipt: TransactionReceipt {
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    to: '0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F',
    from: '0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776',
    contractAddress: null,
    hash: '0xc32c9a7ddcfd29c84915ca77e8df885a70998d216725d5c48e435506e5d12161',
    index: 2,
    blockHash: '0x05fe89a7c818f1d53c955eaeeb2879dc271457a3e6d1ca1373c82b6bb367c775',
    blockNumber: 6059890,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    gasUsed: 25695n,
    blobGasUsed: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 112698n,
    gasPrice: 1000264n,
    blobGasPrice: null,
    type: 2,
    status: 0,
    root: undefined
  },
  shortMessage: 'transaction execution reverted'
}

Code that is generating the error:
import pkg from 'hardhat';
const { ethers } = pkg;
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();

const forwarderArtifact = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./artifacts/contracts/ERC2771Forwarder.sol/ERC2771Forwarder.json'), 'utf-8')
);

class WorldChain {
    async transfer(address, amount, privateKeyForGas, privateKeyForWLD) {
        try {
            const RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL;
            const CONTRACT_ADDRESS_WORLDCHAIN = "0x2cFc85d8E48F8EAB294be644d9E25C3030863003";
            const CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER = "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F";
            const ABI_TRANSFER = [
                "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
                "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
                "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public returns (bool)"
            ];
    
            const providerForGas = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const walletForGas = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForGas, providerForGas);

            const providerForWLD = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const walletForWLD = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForWLD, providerForWLD);

            const forwarder = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER, forwarderArtifact.abi, walletForGas);

            const wldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS_WORLDCHAIN, ABI_TRANSFER, walletForWLD);

            const balance = await wldContract.balanceOf(walletForWLD.address);
            const decimals = await wldContract.decimals();

            const ethBalanceForGas = await providerForGas.getBalance(walletForGas.address);
            console.log("Saldo de ETH en wei para pagar comisiones:", ethBalanceForGas.toString());
            const formattedEthBalanceForGas = ethers.formatUnits(ethBalanceForGas, "ether");
            console.log("Saldo de ETH formateado para pagar comisiones:", formattedEthBalanceForGas);

            const formattedBalance = ethers.formatUnits(balance, decimals).replace('.', ',');
            console.log(`Saldo actual de Worldcoin: ${formattedBalance} WLD`);

            const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amount, decimals);
            const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;
            const forwardRequestData = {
                from: walletForWLD.address,
                to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER,
                value: ethers.parseEther(amount),
                gas: 500000,
                deadline: deadline,
                data: wldContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [address, amountInWei]),
            };

            console.log("Datos para transferir:", forwardRequestData);

            const domain = {
                name: 'ERC2771Forwarder',
                version: '1',
                chainId: 480,
                verifyingContract: CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER
            };

            const types = {
                ForwardRequest: [
                    { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
                    { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
                    { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
                    { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
                    { name: 'deadline', type: 'uint256' },
                    { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
                ]
            };

            const signature = await walletForWLD.signTypedData(domain, types, forwardRequestData);

            forwardRequestData.signature = signature;

            console.log("Firma para transferir:", forwardRequestData.signature);

            const tx = await forwarder.execute(forwardRequestData, {
                /*value: amountInWei,*/
                gasLimit: (500000).toString(),
            });
            console.log(`Transacción enviada: ${tx.hash}`);

            await tx.wait();
            console.log(`Transacción recibida: ${tx.hash}`);

            return {
                status: 'success',
                transactionHash: tx.hash
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return {
                status: 'error',
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    }
}

export default new WorldChain();

I am using the OpenZeppelin ERC2771Forwarder contracts to make the main wallet pay for the gas and the user's private key pay for the WLD.

Silahkon download blokchain melalui aplikasi playstore. Karena anda harus mendownload aplikasi tersebut terlebih dahulu,agar dapat mengoperasikan saldo anda
